# Spark master/worker not writing logs within History Server configuration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Quite new to Spark setup. I want to persist event logs for each separate spark cluster I run. In my setup, `/history-logs` dir is mounted from different locations based on cluster name. The directory's permissions allow read-write for spark user(751).

Config file under `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` for both master and workers is as follows:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir file:///history-logs
spark.history.fs.logDirectory file:///history-logs
```

I'm connecting from Zeppelin and running a simple piece of code:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 5)
println(rdd.sum())
```

No files are being written to the folder though.

If I configure similar parameters in the Zeppellin interpreter itself, at least I see that application log file is created in the directory.

Is it possible to save the logs from master/workers on per-cluster basis? I might be missing something obvious.

Thanks!